# Getting a table from a string in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm trying to get a table (entity) from the entity framework context and all I have is a string parameter input to my service.

In ADO.NET I'd do something like:

var tableName = "tablePrefix" + inputString;

How do I solve this in EF?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: what is your  aim to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To get a Dbset dynamically without knowing the type upfront you can use the Set method on the DbContext. So you could do.

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyType");
var set = myContext.Set(type);
```

Once you have the set you can then query to find an entity by primary key etc.

As Kirill says though, why do you want to do this?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Thanks, going to test it out soon. Looks to be a solution.
The reason is the db design, it contains different types and three resolution levels per type. So when a call comes to the service, I only get a string that tells me which table to retrieve data from.